# How do I find common values within groups in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

My 'dataframe' contain two columns, the first one is the SKU number and the second one is the part number for each SKU number. Some SKUs share same part numbers, how do I find these SKUs that share part numbers?

```
import pandas as pd 
table_teste = pd.read_csv("table.csv")
print(table_teste)[see in the picture attached here the screenshot of the input vales][1]

Output:
           SKU    Part Number
0         4679343         126420
1         4679343         489136
2         4679343         490202
3         4679343         490282
4         4679343         491971
5         4679343         492963
6         4679343         626681
7         4679343         627996
8         4679343         628361
9         4679343         628379
10        4679343         628379
11        4679343         628408
12        4679343         628531
13        4679343        1105601
14        4679343        1140073
15        4679343        2169104
16        4679343        2169104
17        4679343        2169142
18        4679343        2185762
19        4679343        2194712
20        4679343        2195058
21        4679343        2256086
22        4679343        2315522
23        4679343        2315522
24        4679343        2319835
25        4679343        8314101
26        4679343        8314102
27        4679343        8314229
28        4679343        8314231
29        4679343        8314232
...           ...            ...
73953  WRO80CKDWA      W11234774
73954  WRO80CKDWA      W11239503
73955  WRO80CKDWA      W11240332
73956  WRO80CKDWA      W11240358
73957  WRO80CKDWA      W11240361
73958  WRO80CKDWA      W11240362
73959  WRO80CKDWA      W11240363
73960  WRO80CKDWA      W11282632
73961  WRO80CKDWA      W11282632
73962  WRO80CKDWA      W11293453
73963  WRO80CKDWA      W11294381
73964  WRO80CKDWA      W11294503
73965  WRO80CKDWA      W11298984
73966  WRO80CKDWA      W11308860
73967  WRO80CKDWA      W11308879
73968  WRO80CKDWA      W11314128
73969  WRO80CKDWA      W11317776
73970  WRO80CKDWA      W11323281
73971  WRO80CKDWA      W11323282
73972  WRO80CKDWA      W11323283
73973  WRO80CKDWA      W11323284
73974  WRO80CKDWA      W11366199
73975  WRO80CKDWA      W11366205
73976  WRO80CKDWA      W11366209
73977  WRO80CKDWA      W11366214
73978  WRO80CKDWA      W11366215
73979  WRO80CKDWA      W11370412
73980  WRO80CKDWA      W11370419
73981  WRO80CKDWA      W11370494
73982  WRO80CKDWA  ZCOMP_FREIGHT
```

Now I need to generate a matrix that has the SKU numbers in the row and the same SKU numbers in the column and in the matrix the count of how many part numbers the combination of SKU number 1 and SKU number 2 share that are the same. Same thing for SKU number 2 with SKU number 3 and so on. There is 182 SKU numbers in total.

Thank you

Comment: please share a sample data and your code

Comment: SKU   PART-NUMBER
1       A
1 B
2 A
2 C
3 A
3 D

this is just an illustrative sample. now i need to find which  SKUS share same part numbers, some of them might share 70% of their part numbers, other less and other more, for me I need the ones that share at least 50%

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please [edit] your question to include a full [mcve] including sample input data, expected output based on that input, and _code_ for what you've tried so far based on your own research so that we can understand how to help you. Please note: posting unformatted data in a comment does not help us to reproduce your issue

Answer (score 1):

Find all part numbers with more than 1 SKU:

```
partNumber_w_dupSKU = data %>%
  group_by(partNumber) %>%
  summarize(n_SKU = n_distinct(SKU)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  filter(n_SKU > 1)
```

Find all SKU's associated with these part numbers:

```
data %>%
  arrange(SKU) %>%
  filter(partNumber %in% partNumber_w_dupSKU$partNumber)
```

Comment: is this on pandas? cause i cant find summarize option

Comment: @PriscillaSopok This is with R. You had a R tag before, so...

Comment: sorry, my mistake. Do you know the equivalent of these commands to Python?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a groupby() on part numbers which will group your dataframe accordingly 
If you do groupby on SKU numbers then it will show a dataframe with SKU number that share a common part number 
Or vice versa

Answer (score 0):

You can try using groupby, convert the groups to list and reset index.

```py
# dictionary of sku number as key and value as part number
# I'm assuming this is how the df might look like
d = {1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 2, 4: 2, 5: 3, 6: 2, 7: 3}
# making a dataframe out of the dict to resemble df in que
df = pd.DataFrame(d.items(), columns=['SKU Number', 'Part Number'])

df

Output: 
   SKU Number  Part Number
0           1            2
1           2            3
2           3            2
3           4            2
4           5            3
5           6            2
6           7            3
```

```py
# first groupby part numbers
g = df.groupby('Part Number')
# convert groups to list of two-SKU combinations and then reset index to create a new data
x = g['SKU Number'].apply(itertools.combinations(x, 2))).reset_index(name='SKU numbers')

x

Output:

   Part Number                                       SKU numbers
0            2  [(1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 6), (3, 4), (3, 6), (4, 6)]
1            3                          [(2, 5), (2, 7), (5, 7)]
```

^ now we have all two-member SKU combinations for each part number. Let's explode the list in SKU numbers column.

```py
x = x.explode('SKU numbers')
x
out:
   Part Number SKU numbers
0            2      (1, 3)
0            2      (1, 4)
0            2      (1, 6)
0            2      (3, 4)
0            2      (3, 6)
0            2      (4, 6)
1            3      (2, 5)
1            3      (2, 7)
1            3      (5, 7)
```

Now we need to group pairs of SKU numbers and count the part numbers associated with them

```py
x = x.groupby('SKU numbers').count().reset_index()

x
out:
  SKU numbers  Part Number
0      (1, 3)            1
1      (1, 4)            1
2      (1, 6)            1
3      (2, 5)            1
4      (2, 7)            1
5      (3, 4)            1
6      (3, 6)            1
7      (4, 6)            1
8      (5, 7)            1
```

^ Now we have counts for part numbers for each SKU pair. Let's construct the matrix.

```py
import numpy as np


indexes = x['SKU numbers'].values
part_number_counts = x['Part Number'].values

# in my small case, we have 7 unique SKUs
unique_SKUs = 7
# creating a zero matrix so that we can populate part num counts
# for each SKU pair
a = np.zeros((unique_SKUs, unique_SKUs))

a
out:
array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

```py
# split [(x1, y1), (x2, y2) ...] to rows  -> [x1, x2 ...]
#                                 columns -> [y1, y2 ....]
rows, columns = map(np.array , zip(*indexes))

# rows-1, columns-1 are done to make index 0-based
a[rows-1, columns-1] = part_number_counts

a
out:
array([[0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

For the final part, I'm using my indexes(SKU pairs), converting them to 0-based indexes and updating their corresponding part_number_counts to the zero matrix to get the resultant matrix.

The resultant matrix will have shape of (unique_SKU_numbers, unique_SKU_numbers) and the value i,j would correspond to the part_number_counts

Comment: thank you Gowtham, what I need exactly is a matrix showing me for each combination of SKUS how many part number they share the same?

Comment: If you could add a small example of input and expected output, I can help you better  (: . Since you had asked in the question, you wanted to know the SKUs that share a part number, I had written the above code.

Comment: Sorry this is my first time using StackOverflow.

Comment: No problem :)

You can edit the question and add sample input and sample output.

Comment: See above, I added some extra info

Comment: I can see the code, don't see the screenshot though.

you can maybe try pasting the output inside the code snippet just like  I've done in my answer?

Comment: I just added the output example

Comment: @PriscillaSopok I have updated the answer and also demonstrated on a small example. Hope it is useful

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213773/discussion-between-gowtham-ramesh-and-priscilla-sopok).